# Drop Down Menu not pushing the contents down in IE7

Tags: html

I am new on this forum.

I am developing a website using HTML5 and CSS with responsive design. I have a navigation menu which behaves as a simple drop down menu for desktop and laptop

but for tablet and mobile it has a menu button

By clicking on the menu button, it alternatively appear and disappear with display:blocks otherwise display:none and pushes the contents of main area downward

All works fine in Firefox, Chrome and IE but It is not pushing the contents down in IE7

I am stuck here since two days

Here is my HTML Code

```
<div id="wrapper">
<header id="topHeader">
<div id="topDiv">
<div id="mainDiv">
<div id="logo">
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"> <a itemprop="url" href="/Default.aspx"> <img itemprop="logo" src="/App_Themes/Default/Images//logo.png" alt=""> </a> </div>
    </div>
    <div id="navDiv">

    <nav id="nav">
      <ul id="navigation">
        <li id="mobileSignup"> <a href="#"><h3>Signup</h3></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/component/component-overview.aspx">
          <h3>Components</h3>
          </a></li>
        <li><a href="/pricing.aspx">
          <h3>Pricing</h3>
          </a></li>
        <li> <a href="/consulting/partners.aspx">
          <h3>Partners</h3>
          </a>


        </li>
        <li> <a href="/about/about-contact.aspx">
          <h3> About &#x025be;</h3>
          </a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="/about/blog.aspx" >
              <h3>Blog</h3>
              </a></li>
            <li><a href="/about/about-contact.aspx" >
              <h3>Contact</h3>
              </a></li>
            <li><a href="/about/about-FAQ.aspx" >
              <h3>FAQ</h3>
              </a></li>                
            <li><a href="/about/about-timeline.aspx" >
              <h3>Timeline</h3>
              </a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="register">
      <div id="contact">
        <h5> <a href="tel:18666686402"><img src="/App_Themes/Default/Images/Phone.png" id="phoneImg" alt="" /></a><span id="phoneNumber"> 1 866 668 6402</span></h5>
      </div>
      <div id="signup"><a href="/signup.aspx" onMouseOver="document.getElementById('signupImg').src='/App_Themes/Default/Images/SignUpbuttonOnHover.png';"  onMouseOut="document.getElementById('signupImg').src='/App_Themes/Default/Images/SignUpbutton.png'"><img src="/App_Themes/Default/Images/SignUpbutton.png" id="signupImg" alt=""></a>
      <a href="#" onclick="menu_visibility('navDiv');"><img src="/App_Themes/Default/Images/menuButton.png" alt="" id="menuButton"></a>

      </div>
      <div id="login">
        <h3>
        <a href="login"> Login</a>
        </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </header>
</div>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Here is my css code for desktop menu

```
    /*===========================================================================
    * Horizontal Navigation
    * Setting up the nav in the middle of the mainDiv
    =============================================================================*/
#navDiv {
    display:inline;
    position:absolute;
    /*display:block;*/
    margin-left:30px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
/*===========================================================================
 * Setting up the main menu at a margin of 20px from logo div
 =============================================================================*/
#nav ul {
    /*margin-left: 20px;*/
    list-style-type:none;
    list-style:none;
}
/*===========================================================================
 * Setting up the list item as the main menu items
 =============================================================================*/
ul#navigation li {
    display:block;
    float: left;
}
/*===========================================================================
 * Setting up the margin, color, text-decoration and display style for main menu
 =============================================================================*/
#nav > ul > li > a {
    margin: 27px 15px 27px 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
/*===========================================================================
 * Changing the background image for main menu for hover effects
 =============================================================================*/
#nav ul li:hover {
    background: url("Images/MenuOnHover.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
/*===========================================================================
 * Setting up the Drop Down Menus
 * Making it visible for main menu hover effects
 =============================================================================*/
#nav ul#navigation li ul {
    display: none;  
}
 ul#navigation ul li {
    clear: both;
    width: 130px;
    border: 0 none;
    padding: 5px;
}
#nav ul#navigation li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}
/*===========================================================================
 * Making basic decorations of drop down menu
 =============================================================================*/
ul#navigation ul, ul#navigation ul li ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99999;
    width: 130px;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #ccc;
    opacity: 0;
}
ul#navigation ul li {
    clear: both;
    width: 130px;
    border: 0 none;
    padding: 5px;
}
ul#navigation ul li a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul#navigation ul li:hover {
    background: #1E77A0;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 125px;
}
ul#navigation ul li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
/*===============================================================================
 * menuButton for tablet and mobile, It is hidden by default
 ===============================================================================*/
#register #signup #menuButton {
    display:none;
}
}
```

and here is my code for mobile menu

```
  /*===========================================================================
 * Vertical Navigation
 * Setting up the nav in the middle of the mainDiv
 =============================================================================*/
#navDiv {
    float:left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #161616;
    display:none;
}
#nav {
    width: 25%;
    background: #161616;
}
#nav ul li {
    list-style:none;
    list-style-type:none;
    position:relative;
}
#nav ul li h3 {
    margin: 12px auto;
}
#nav ul  li  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#fff;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul li {
    margin:12px;
}
#nav ul li ul {
    display: none;
    opacity: 1;
}
#navigation li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    margin: 15px 10px;
}
ul#navigation #mobileSignup {
    display: block;
}

/*===========================================================================
 * register div contains the signup and login div
 * Setting up the register div position and text color
 =============================================================================*/
#register {
    position:absolute;
    top: 1px;
    right: 2%;
    width:130px;
}
#register #contact {
    float:left;
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-right:15px;
}
#register #contact #phoneNumber {
    display:none;
}
#register #signup {
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-left: 3%;
}
#register #signup #signupImg {
    display:none;
}
#register #signup #menuButton {
    display:inline;
    margin-top:10px;
}
#register #login a {
    margin-right:3%;
}
```

Please help me to find out this bug for IE7. Please it is an humble request that don't refer to JQuery or javascript based menu as I don't want to use them.

Comment: One nice way to debug this would be to use the IE8 developer tools then use compatibility mode (converts to IE7).  This may help you dig into the issue.

Comment: Thanks dseibert, I am using Windows 8 with IE10. Will you please guide me how to debug this issue with IE10 developers tools.

Comment: Let me know if this works for you: http://techathlon.com/internet-explorer-10-run-compatibility-mode/

Comment: Yes, I am already using the same developer tools for IE10 but still unable to find the solution that's the reason I have posted my question here.

Comment: Here is something that might help.  It seems like a pretty nice list of inconsistencies in IE versions.  (6/7/8) http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/14/css-differences-in-internet-explorer-6-7-and-8/

Comment: still facing same problem.